# Explaination why Ionic can't set POST variables sent to php - isset($_POST()) always false?

Tags: php, ionic-framework

**My Question**

Apart from CORS, does anyone has an explanation, why Ionic can't send Post data to the php and php can't see the set data through

```
   isset($_POST(u_name))
```

For an instances, I tried to send some login information to my php file "login_check.php".

Below is my controller.js

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup, $state) {

       $scope.data = {};

       $scope.login = function() {
            console.log("Login pge :: getlogin");
            var link = 'http://192.168.1.2:80/mySite/login_check.php';
            var request = $http.post(link, { "u_name": $scope.data.username, "u_pass": $scope.data.password }, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} );

            request.success(function(response) { 
                console.log(response);  
                if(response.success === 1 ){
                    $state.go('tab.dash');
                    console.log(response);

                }else{
                    //error handling
                }

            })
            request.error(function(response) {
                 //error handling
            });
        } 
   })
```

and I tried to read it through my "login_check.php" as below

```
<?php
    include_once './database_conn.php'; //my DB configuration details

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();
    // check for required fields
    if(isset($_POST('u_name')) && isset($_POST('u_pass'))){

        $username = trim($_POST['u_name']);
        $pass = trim($_POST['u_pass']);

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DbConnection();
        // mysql checking the login
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT tu_user, tu_pass FROM twp_users WHERE tu_user = '$username' AND tu_pass = '$pass'");

        if (!empty($result)) {
            // check if row selected or not
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                // successfully retrieve data into database
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "successful";

                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {

                // failed to retrieve row
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Login failed. Either username or password is incorrect";

                echo json_encode($response);
            }

        } else{
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No login found";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }


   } else {
         // required field is missing
         $response["success"] = 0;
         $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is/are missing";
         echo json_encode($response);

   }    
?>
```

Whenever I tried to send data it always says that

```
 "Required field(s) is/are missing"
```

**NOTE :**

- Further my point is, I'm trying to use the **same database** and **same server side scripting** on several client ends. So far Java EE and Android is returning data from this php.
- if I use $_GET() and send data through URL this php works well with Cordova/Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Line:

```
if(isset($_POST(u_name)) && isset($_POST(u_pass)))
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST['u_name']) && isset($_POST['u_pass']))
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for that. My mistake. That was in my original code. Has mistakenly removed them quotes in the question. I edited it. That doesn't work......

Comment: Try debugging it by adding this code at the top and see the response: `$response["success"] = 0; $response["message"] = $_POST['u_name'] . " " . $_POST['u_pass']; echo json_encode($response);exit;`

Comment: It gave me this <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\TestCordova\login_check.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />

Comment: Result of a Function Call? You are still using `$_POST()` instead of `$_POST[]`. Please make sure you are making changes to the right file. There might be multiple versions of your app. And use the previously mentioned code at the top of `if (isset...)`

Answer (score 0):

Forgot quotes and bracket

```
if(isset($_POST['u_name']) && isset($_POST['u_pass']))
```

change mysql query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT tu_user, tu_pass FROM twp_users WHERE tu_user = '{$username}' AND tu_pass = '{$pass}'");
```

Comment: Sorry for that. My mistake. That was in my original code. Has mistakenly removed them quotes in the question. I edited it. That doesn't work......

Comment: @Thush-Fdo Put html code will also be investigated.